# Return true or false not working in JavaScript 

Tags: javascript, html, forms, return-value

My return values are not working, and I need them to work so I can validate the page.  I have a function in a function because there will be more code written which will require that kind of setup.

Here is the JavaScript code:

```
var postalconfig = /^\D{1}\d{1}\D{1}\-?\d{1}\D{1}\d{1}$/;

function outer(){
    function checkpostal(postal_code){
      if (postalconfig.test(document.myform.postal_code.value)) {
        alert("VALID SSN");
        return true;
      } else {
        alert("INVALID SSN");
        return false;
      }
    }
  checkpostal();
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<form name="myform" action="index.php" onSubmit="return outer();" method="post">
    Postal Code <input name="postal_code"  type="text" />
    <input name="Submit" type="submit"  value="Submit Form" >
</form>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?  Do you mean that the function returns the correct result, but the submission happens anyway?

Comment: with better formatting sometimes these things popout at us. I suggest a notepad type program like notepad++ if you're not already using a javascript oriented IDE to help you keep your code organized and properly indented. (reindent as C style code usually works pretty well).

Comment: Seconding @drachenstern's point. [jsbeautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/) is a good tool for this too.

Comment: Thanks guys I'll work on better formatting for the future.

Comment: Well the fact that you're grasping the concepts of closures is good and well enough. Keep up the good work and come on back with more questions as you get them ;)

Answer (score 7):

Change `checkpostal();` to `return checkpostal();`

like this:

```
var postalconfig = /^\D{1}\d{1}\D{1}\-?\d{1}\D{1}\d{1}$/;

function outer(){   

  function checkpostal(postal_code) {
    if (postalconfig.test(document.myform.postal_code.value)) {
      alert("VALID SSN");
      return true;
    } else {
      alert("INVALID SSN");
      return false;
    }
  }

  return checkpostal();

}
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is that you are getting the return value of `outer`, but `outer` doesn't return anything.  `return true` (or `false`) only affects the current function, in this case, `checkpostal`.

You need to get `outer` to return the return value of `checkpostal`:

```
function outer() {
    function checkpostal(postal_code) {
        if (postalconfig.test(document.myform.postal_code.value)) {
            alert("VALID SSN");
            return true;
        } else {
            alert("INVALID SSN");
            return false;
        }
    }

    return checkpostal();
}
```

Comment: You need a space in there. :)

Comment: So it's like the return-value is stuck inside the inner function and doesn't reach the onSubmit?  Am I on the right line of thinking here?

Comment: @Christopher Sort of. `return` exits the current function. It does *not* exit parent/calling functions. If you want to return from them, you have to do so explicitly by passing along the return value.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like at the end of `outer()` it should be

```
return checkpostal();
```

rather than just

```
checkpostal();
```

The call to `checkpostal()` may return correctly, but onsubmit won't get the result, since `outer()` isn't returning anything.

Comment: So it's like the return-value is stuck inside the inner function and doesn't reach the onSubmit?  Am I on the right line of thinking here?

Comment: Sure.  Another way to think of it is that onSubmit is calling a function and expecting that function to return something.  What happens *inside* that function doesn't matter -- it isn't returning anything.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to return the call to checkpostal:

```
function outer(){   

    function checkpostal(postal_code){
 if (postalconfig.test(document.myform.postal_code.value)) {
  alert("VALID SSN");
  return true;
 } else {
  alert("INVALID SSN");
  return false;
 }
}

return checkpostal();

}
```